Need help moving two div's next to another div
Hello All I am trying to move a4 to the area shown in the img but i cant find how or any related posts on how to get 2 divs to the right of the  1 div, Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!
This is what it should look like:
What It Should Look Like:
Here is the code that I have tried:


.post-background {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}


.post-area {
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.1);
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid purple;

}

.a1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 99.2%;
    height: 75px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 5px solid red;
    display: block;
}

.a2 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0 0, 255, 0.5);
    border: 5px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;

}

.a3 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    height: 75px;
    background: rgba(0 255, 0, 0.5);
    border: 5px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8%;
}

.a4 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    height: 75px;
    background: rgba(0, 229, 255, 0.5);
    border: 5px solid rgb(0, 229, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8%;

}
<div class="post-background">
<div class="post-area">

<div class="a1">
<h1>a1</h1>
</div>

<div class="a2">
<h1>a2</h1>
</div>

<div class="a3">
<h1>a3</h1>
</div>

<div class="a4">
<h1>a4</h1>
</div>

</div>
</div>




Grid is best for two-dimensional layouts.


.post-background {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.post-area {
  background: rgb(128 0 128 / 0.1);
  border: 5px solid purple;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  gap: 0.5em 5%;
}

.a1 {
  background: rgb(255 0 0 / 0.5);
  border: 5px solid red;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.a2 {
  background: rgb(0 0 255 / 0.5);
  border: 5px solid blue;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}

.a3 {
  background: rgba(0 255 0 / 0.5);
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.a4 {
  background: rgba(0 229 255 / 0.5);
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 229, 255);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}
<div class="post-background">
<div class="post-area">

<div class="a1">
<h1>a1</h1>
</div>

<div class="a2">
<h1>a2</h1>
</div>

<div class="a3">
<h1>a3</h1>
</div>

<div class="a4">
<h1>a4</h1>
</div>

</div>
</div>




You can try this approach :
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .row1{
            border: 3px solid red;
            padding: 10px 0;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(240, 136, 136);
        }
        .container{
            margin : auto;
            border: 2px solid rgb(137, 137, 248);
            max-width: 60%;
        }
        .first-section{
            text-align: center;
            width: 60%;
            min-height: 100px;
            background-color: rgb(131, 131, 177);
            border: 3px solid blue;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        .row2{
            display: flex;
        }
        .a3{
            width:20%;
            background-color: rgb(140, 238, 140);
            border: 3px solid green;
        }
        .a4{
            width:20%;
            background-color: rgb(140, 238, 140);
            border: 3px solid green;
        }
        .second-section{
            margin-top: 5px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-end;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width:40%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row1">
            a1
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <div class="first-section">
                a2
            </div>
            <div class="second-section">
                <div class="a3">
                    a3
                </div>
                <div class="a4">
                    a4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>




   .post-background {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .post-area {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.1);
        display: block;
        border: 5px solid purple;
    
    }
    
    .a234 {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      margin-top: 1.5%;
    }
    
    .a34 {
      width: 30%;
    }
    
    .a1 {
        text-align: center;
        width: 99.5%;
        height: 75px;
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border: 5px solid red;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .a2 {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 70%;
        height: 200px;
        background: rgba(0 0, 255, 0.5);
        border: 5px solid blue;
    }
    
    .a3 {
        display: block;
        height: 75px;
        background: rgba(0 255, 0, 0.5);
        border: 5px solid green;
        margin-left: 40%;
        margin-bottom: 9%;
    }
    
    .a4 {
        display: block;
        height: 75px;
        background: rgba(0, 229, 255, 0.5);
        border: 5px solid rgb(0, 229, 255);
        margin-left: 40%;
    }
<div class="post-background">
      <div class="post-area">
        <div class="a1">
          <h1>a1</h1>
        </div>
    
        <div class="a234">
          <div class="a2">
            <h1>a2</h1>
          </div>
          
          <div class="a34">
            <div class="a3">
              <h1>a3</h1>
            </div>
    
            <div class="a4">
              <h1>a4</h1>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>



